# How to make a discord bot react to a edited command?

Tags: python, python-3.x, discord.py

Now imagine you typed a wrong command then you edit the message with proper command but the bot doesn't respond it so you have to type the whole command again, what i want my bot to do is: I will Type wrong command `!pimg` and I edit the message back to `!ping` then the bot should realize its a command.

How can I make my bot do it

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can achieve this by using the [`discord.on_message_edit`](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api.html?highlight=edit#discord.on_message_edit) event and by attempting to process the newly edited command with [`discord.ext.commands.Bot.process_commands`](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/ext/commands/api.html?highlight=process#discord.ext.commands.Bot.process_commands):

```
@client.event
async def on_message_edit(before, after):
    try:
        await bot.process_commands(after) # Bot will attempt to process the new edited command
    except:
        raise error
```

Answer (score 2):

Yes there is way to do that using "Edit Events", you might be looking for `discord.on_message_edit(before,after)`

source: https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api.html?#event-reference

Comment: I can use it but after getting message how will i make the bot run the command.

Comment: I guess you didnt understand me think i have big code for a single command then i can't just copy and paste it right it will simply eat up space

Comment: @BluTenGaming you should really post your code (at least an important part of your code) otherwise i cant really know what you want.